# Deleting Cloud Storage Objects in Batch

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Whats the best way to delete many cloudstorage objects? I have a bucket that contains ~500K objects and I'd like to delete them all.

Do you I have to make 1 api request for each object I want to delete or is there some sort of batch method? I'm currently using gsutil to delete one at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make 1 api request for each object. The simplest way to accomplish this would be with [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil):

```
$ gsutil -m rm gs://bucket_with_many_objects/**
```

The -m option enables multithreading, which will delete many objects in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Note that with gsutil the "*" wildcard will only match the top-level objects (up to the next "/" in the path name). If you want to delete all the objects you can either use:

```
$ gsutil -m rm -R gs://bucket_with_many_objects
```

or

```
$ gsutil -m rm gs://bucket_with_many_objects/**
```

Mike Schwartz, Google Cloud Storage Team

Comment: Hi Mike, do you plan a batch delete method for java GCS Json api? Otherwise we have to use raw json calls via https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch, which is to be honest a pain.

Comment: Or something like `$storageService->objects->deleteCollection($condition);` in just 1 request?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, with a bucket containing over 800,000 objects, the **gsutil -m rm gs://bucket-name** method does work, but takes a long time as it is essentially still deleting each object one at a time.

After contacting the Cloud Storage team at Google, they pointed me in the direction of bucket lifecycle policies, although not instant, they allow you to mass delete objects in a more efficient way.

I have written a [blog post on Deleting Full Buckets](http://blog.iangsy.com/2014/04/google-cloud-storage-deleting-full.html) using this method.

Comment: Thanks for writing up that blob posting. A couple of suggestions you might incorporate into that post: (1) Regarding your comment that the rb command doesn't provide a way to force the deletion of the bucket and its contents: gsutil rm -r gs://bucket-name will do that. (2) To speed up further you can run commands on multiple machines, e.g., on machine 1 run "gsutil -m rm -r gs://bucket-name/a*", on machine 2 run "gsutil -m rm -r gs://bucket-name/b*" etc. How you divide up the work depends on how your objects are named, but hopefully you get the idea.